Pressure at tail end of a water pipe
I was wondering about what is the pressure at end B based on these requirements:
the flow velocity through the pipe is vcon(m/s) and flow rate is q(m^3/s), no requirement for delivery pressure at B, length of pipe is L(m), B is higher than A in height.
By using bernoulli's theorem, pressure/head required to pump water from A to be B will be = Head loss due to friction + Potential head due to height difference between A and B. Does this mean that water pressure at point B will be zero?

Yes, if it is open  to the atmosphere at B, the gauge pressure at B is zero.

Thank you Chet Miller!
